# Add an object to an Array based on dictionary Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I believe this would be an algorithm question, so it doesn't matter what language this is in, although I think in my case it will be implemented in jquery.

So the idea is I have two arrays of type Object.  In this object there are many variables, but the only relevant one to this is a String.  Lets say for argument sake, I have array `[A, A, A, A, B, B, E, E, F]` and the 'dictionary' array `[A, B, C, D, E, F]`.  Whenever I want to add something to the first array, I want it to be added by the location of the object in the second array.  So for instance, if I wanted to add `D`, the first array would now look like `[A, A, A, A, B, B, D, E, E, F]`.

To add `D`, there is not necessarily a `C` or `D` to search for to put the `D` in after.  In addition, there can be repeats like in the example.  The array could also be empty that the program is adding `'D'` to.  Also, if there are already `D`s in the first array, the `D` would go after the last `D`.

Important: The letters I used are only for clarification sake, the actual code uses words that are NOT in alphabetical order, so solutions using alphabetical order do NOT work in this instance.

Is there a better solution to this then brute force?

Comment: Do you mean like using the dictionary to determine an insertion order?  Basically sorting by a dictionary?

Comment: Perhaps keep track of the index in your array where the block of `A`s, `B`s, etc. *ends*. In your case, that'd be `{A:4, B:6, C:6, D:6, E:8, F:9}`. When you want to add a value, say, a `D`, do so at the given index, and then increment the indices for `D` and all values after it.

Comment: Yeah, spot on! Just so you know, it isn't actually a dictionary, but two arrays.  Basically the second arrays order is used to determine where in the first array I add that object.

Comment: Mauris: I can do that, I just need to talk to my team about making that change to the structure.  Thanks.